# Laravel Set Up Email Variable Not Working on Production?

Tags: laravel

I tries to setup enviroment email by following to send email on production:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.example.sg 
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@examle.sg
MAIL_PASSWORD="my_password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@example.sg
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

But, It's not working as expected. Do you know why is not working?

Comment: have you run `php artisan config:cache` on the production server?

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
mail_username=test@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=test
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: @kapitan I already tried with it sir.

Comment: are you telling us that the same setting runs on your developer machine?

Comment: For local enviroment, I used to sent email by gmail. but for production I buy this email for production.

Comment: What the error you get? Check the error logs for the error (`/storage/log/`)

Comment: @EsTeAa I checked it but, there is no any error.

Comment: Then you need to catch the error with try-catch